# Avoid recursion in predicate

Tags: prolog

I have the following question for the following predicate, how can i drop the recursive call `f(T,S1)` from both predicates.

Flow model:
(i,o)

```
f([],0).
f([H|T],S):-
    f(T,S1),
    S1 > 2,!,
    S is S1 + H.
f([_|T],S):-
    f(T,S1),
    S is S1 + 1.
```

This is a trick question, and I am not that good with prolog. the second predicate fails always.= > can be droped, but  what about the second. As I see this method is a list elements counter. Thanks.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Why should this be a trick question?

Comment: since the `S is S1 + H` never occurs?

Comment: For lists that are longer than three it is relevant!

Comment: Why do you want to drop the recursive call? Recursion is how one does does list processing in Prolog.

Comment: This is an exercises have seen and i was curious, what  may i missed and if it is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this is a complex issue. You assume it is a trick question, but is it really one? How can we be sure? I will let `library(clpfd)` do the thinking for me. First I will rewrite your program:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

fx([],0).
fx([H|T],S):-
    fx(T,S1),
    S1 #> 2,
    S #= S1 + H.
fx([_|T],S):-
    fx(T,S1),
    S1 #=< 2,
    S #= S1 + 1.
```

(And just a remark: putting these tests after the recursion twice will make this program require exponentially many inferences, but let's stick to it...)

So I would like to reason about that program in the most general manner. Therefore, I will not take concrete values and then try to figure out a theory. Instead I will ask very general questions (using SICStus):

```
| ?- assert(clpfd:full_answer).
yes
| ?- length(L,N), fx(L,S).
   L = [],
   N = 0,
   S = 0 ?
;
   L = [_A],
   N = 1,
   S = 1 ?
;
   L = [_A,_B],
   N = 2,
   S = 2 ?
;
   L = [_A,_B,_C],
   N = 3,
   S = 3 ?
;
   L = [_A,_B,_C,_D],
   N = 4,
   _A+3#=S,
   _A in inf..sup,
   S in inf..sup ?
;
   L = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E],
   N = 5, ...
```

So please look at the answers `N = 0` up to `N = 3`: There no constraints are involved, effectively all the elements of the list `[_A,_B,...]` are ignored. However, starting with `N = 4` the first element `_A` now influences the "sum" `S` since the equation `S #= _A+3` holds! With larger values things become more and more complex.

In any case, I cannot see how this could be a trick question. The last three elements are ignored. Well, that's kind of a trick. But otherwise elements (or at least some of them) influence the outcome!

Comment: But then how comes my test with functions: `13 ?- f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,1000,17,18], R).
R = 17.` returns the umber of elements of the list

Comment: I get with your program `f/2` **and** with my version `fx/2` rather `R = 110.` We must be missing something!

Answer (score 2):

How about the following? It's efficient!-)

```
f([],0).
f([H|T],S):-
    f(T,S1),
    (  S1 > 2
    -> S is S1 + H
    ;  S is S1 + 1
    ).
```

Comment: Thanks,  but as you did it is  still required a recursive call, so there must be   some rec call (that was my taught also)